# How to retrieve CSV headers only from S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ruby-csv

I have a large csv file in S3 bucket, I just wanted to get the headers only. Iam using ruby aws-sdk . Any pointers? I needed headers only and I dont want to read the whole csv just to get the headers